# How can I convert my java code containing simple for loop using stream and lambda?

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to convert old-style for loop with some newly generated variables and if statements int the new style using java streams and lambda expression.

```
    for (MyClass a : list_1) {
      if (a.myMethod() != null) {
        List<Integer> list_2 = myMap.get(/*some code*/);                 
        if (list_2 == null) {
          list_2 = new ArrayList<>();
          myMap.put(/*some code*/);
        }
        list_2.add(/*some code*/);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a closer look to the different parts.

First you need a stream:

```
list_1.stream()
```

Next you have an `if`. This can most of the time be converted into `filter`:

```
.filter(a -> a.myMethod() != null)
```

Then, you want to do some things with your data. you can use forEach for that:

```
list_1.stream()
  .filter(a -> a.myMethod() != null)
  .forEach(a -> {
    // only put list in if absent
    myMap.putIfAbsent(/* your stuff */);
    myMap.get(/* some code */).add(/* your stuff */);
  });
```

Comment: Where should I create `list_2` ? @christian-wörz

Comment: Where you need it. I think you just put it inside your map and then get it from your map.